# PWA opening black white screen for almost 30 seconds before loading the app

Tags: reactjs, progressive-web-apps

I have PWA published in playstore, once i download it like normal app to my phone and try to open it, its bringing white screen instead of the splash screen, BUT when i open the PWA website add the app to home screen through the browser by clicking the plus sign in my chrome browser and then try to open it by clicking the icon added to home screen, it opens properly with the splash screen, please help me know what am i doing wrong.